# TimeMeasurementStart and End

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I have a problem with the time measure. I want to measure the productiontime. Time start before a assembler, where i put different agent together. On the picture you see the following issue.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa4qf.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the following image, every timeMeasureEnd has to be associated with a timeMeasureStart. If you don't do it, then you will get that error.

[image: timeMeasure]

For the assembler, it is not possible to use the timeMeasure blocks because the agents entering are different than the one exiting, and timeMeasure blocks can only measure times for the same agent... Instead you should record the processing times using a dataSet or a statistics element from the analysis palette and do something similar to this:
[image: dataset]

Comment: I'm using an assembler block. If I add a timeMeasurementStart in front of input1 and a timeMeasurementEnd after the assembler it throws the error in the image above. If I add another timeMeasurementStart in front of input2 it throws the same error.

Comment: oh... if it's an assembler, you can't do it because the agent at the exit is different than the agents that enter the assembler... so you have to use something different.. not the timeMeasurement block...

Comment: and what you use depends on how you want to measure the time.. when the first part arrives? When all the parts arrived? When some of the parts arrive?

Comment: I used in all 4 assembler and i want measure the time from first assembler til the fourth assembler (to simulate pruductionline).

Comment: It works. Thank your very much for your help. :) I did it with the dataset and a variabel with the initialtime code.